# How do Transcribe URLs work?

Tags: transcribe

I've just purchased Transcribe and can't quite figure something out (also using Structure).

http://screencast.com/t/YQ7ynAZi

So I create a test entry, save, go back into it and create an associated entry. After this I can see my 2 pages on 2 urls:

/en/test
/ru/test

Perfect.

However, if I now and go edit either entry, the URL changes, e.g.

/en/test-1
/ru/test

If the segment after the language is not the same, then there is no real point having a language segment at all! e.g.

/en/test-en
/ru/test-ru

Is not ideal and may as well be:

/test-en
/test-ru

Is this intended functionality?

Answer (score 2):

The second segment in this case is the URL title (test) which must be unique so yes 'test' and 'test-1' would be created initially from attempting to create 2 entries with the URL title of 'test'.

'test' and 'test-1' are URL Titles created when you created 2 entries called 'test'. This isn't related to Transcribe as such but is the way EE handles URL titles.

So what I'm saying is that each entry has a unique URL title, regardless of it being a translation of another entry. This allows you to have a completely different structure with URL's specific to that language. So the URL would be the word 'test' in Russian for the other entry. This way you could also potentially have a different site structure between different languages.

A typical URL structure would be: /language/template-group/template/url-title/ e.g /en/news/item/test/

So yes this is pretty much intended behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

What seems to be a bug, is actually a feature.

ExpressionEngine wants unique URL titles for each entry. While this may seem limiting, it's actually what you want. URL titles that reflect the language the page is in will help search engines and users understand your content.

```
/en/about-us   
/es/sobre-nosotros   
/de/wir-uber-uns   
/fr/a-propos-de-nous
```

I could see how you might have URL title overlaps like with the case of /en/test and /ru/test. But you can use Pages or Structure URLs like this since they are matching against the full URI. So while your URL title would automatically be changed to "test-1" to avoid duplicates, the Page or Structure URL could still be /ru/test. I just tried it out and it seems to be working.